# How to write this pattern in 2D array?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to write a program that displays the following pattern in 2D array:

```
1  2  3  4  5
16 17 18 19 6
15 24 25 20 7
14 23 22 21 8
13 12 11 10 9
```

My code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include<iomanip>

    using namespace std;
    #define SIZE 5

     int main()
     {
         int i, j, n, x;
         int array[SIZE][SIZE];
         int left, top;

         left = 0;
         n    = 1;

         cout<<"Enter dimension of array pattern:";
         cin>>x;
         while(x<1||x>6){
             cout<<"Invalid entry. Enter a number greater than 0 and less than 6";
cin>>x; 
         }

         top  = x-1;

         for(i=1;i<=x/2;i++,left++,top--){

            for(j=left;j<=top;j++,n++) 
            array[left][j]=n;

            for(j=left+1;j<top;j++,n++)
             array[j][top]=n;

            for(j=top;j>left;j--,n++)
            array[top][j]=n;

            for(j=top;j>left;j--,n++)
            array[j][left]=n;

         }

         for(i=0; i<x; i++)
         {
             for(j=0; j<x; j++)
             {
                 cout<<setw(3)<<array[i][j];

             }
        cout<<endl;

         }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
    }
```

It works alright for even inputs, but gives the last value as garbage for odd numbers.
\n
\n
Input

```
5
```

Output

```
1  2  3  4  5
16 17 18 19 6
15 24700383242 20 7
14 23 22 21 8
13 12 11 10 9
```

Any and every help will be appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated, but note that `while(x<1||x>6){ ... }` can cause an endless loop, because you don't modify `x` inside the loop. There should be `cin>>x;` inside the loop.

Comment: I can't point my finger at any particular bug, but I think the value of the center never get's written for uneven `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For odd numbers, you're never changing the center value, so it will be uninitialized. Reading it out then is undefined behavior, which often manifests as getting a garbage value. You can fix it by extending the loop to also run on that center field:

```
for (i = 1; i <= (x / 2)+1; i++, left++, top--) {
```

Or, since it's rather easy to figure out what value it will have, you can just fill it in manually after the loop:

```
if (x%2 == 1)
    array[x/2][x/2] = x * x;
```

---

Also, don't forget to read in a new number when the user enters an invalid one:

```
while (x < 1 || x>6) {
    cout << "Invalid entry. Enter a number greater than 0 and less than 6";
    cin >> x;
}
```